# Move files to directories

Tags: perl, file, directory, rename

Is there any reason why the following construction would not work? The file list contains file names. The name list contains a list of names that when matched as a substring to a file name, causes the loop to move the file to the directory called $name. It seems like it should work but it is not moving files. What is a better way to construct this?

```
 FILE: for my $file (@file_list) {

  for my $name (@name_list) {

    if ($file =~ /^\Q$name\E/) {
      rename "/Users/path/to/file/I/need/to/move/$file", "/Users/path/to/directory/i/need/to/move/file/to/$name/$file" or die "rename failed because: $!\n";
     next FILE;
    }
  }
  print "no match for $file\n";
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam looks like PHP

Comment: This looks more like Perl than PHP (the `for my $var` and `=~` are among the signs).

Comment: The language is perl.

Comment: Oh, and `FILE:` is a loop label that should be attached to the code jst before the first `for`.

Comment: right, thanks! that was a typo. I fixed the code, but as is still doesn't move my files. It does make the matches, though.

Answer (score 0):

Right code:

```
for my $file (@file_list) {
  my $found = 0;
  for my $name (@name_list) {
    if ($file =~ /^\Q$name\E/) {
      print "failed to rename $file\n" unless rename "/Users/path/to/file/I/need/to/move/$file", "/Users/path/to/directory/i/need/to/move/file/to/$name/$file";
      $found = 1;
      last;
    }
  }
  print "no match for $file\n" unless $found;
}
```

Comment: Why, @Jack, is this a better formulation?

Comment: If file not found you code will exit (rename with die), but this will continue and print error message...

Comment: Actually, I'm getting lot's of "failed to renames..." this way, too. Yeah, the program continues, which is good. But the files are not moving still. grr....

Comment: Do you have this `/Users/path/to/file/I/need/to/move` and this `/Users/path/to/directory/i/need/to/move/file/to` dirs?

Comment: You could use `@file_list = glob('/Users/path/to/file/I/need/to/move/*');` to collect right `@file_list`.

Comment: I have all the directories, which are blank, already made. they are named the same as the names in @name_list.